# EACCES permission denied

Tags: javascript, server, localhost, web-development-server, nodejs-server

I was trying to host a server and listening to port 80 using NodeJS

[I was trying to run this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDCm6.png)
[And This was the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWhSM.png)
[I also checked this whether the port was already listening to something, can this be the reason? If yes then how can I fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLxGT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it is not required to specify a host.
Anyway it seems to be a firewall problem.
nodejs needs do use the ports in order to serve the web page.

Moreover i dont think yout file would be presented.
use `res.sendFile()` or get comfortable to express.js, which is a great
framework for node.js in order to simplify your server-side code.

i hope i was able to help you